# CSS Toggle Navigation Horizontally as Well as Vertically on Screen Re-Size

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to implement a responsive navigation.  Here is a fiddle of what I have done so far: https://jsfiddle.net/a16qwd20/4/

For some reason the Javascript doesn't work and the menu doesn't display in JS fiddle, but it works fine in my code wrapped in  tags.

In it's current state the navigation links display correctly above 580px but the menu icon is still visible.  I would like the menu icon to be visible only when the display is below 580px when above 580 JUST the links!

Here is my CSS for the Navigation before the media query kicks in:

```
#navigation {
 max-width: 100%;
 background-color: #333;
 padding: 0 1.5% 0 1.5%;
 margin: 0px;
}

#navigation ul {
 padding: 0px;
}

#navigation ul li {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 10px 1.5% 10px 1.5% ;
}

#navigation ul li a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-size: 1.2em;
}

#navigation ul li a:hover {
 color: #000000;
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't told the button to hide at all so just add this to the main CSS

```
.menu_button {
display: none;
}
```

The button becomes visible when the media query kicks in.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/a16qwd20/11/)

Comment: Typical.  Something so bloody simple!  Thanks for spotting that Paulie and appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to accomplish that.
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a16qwd20/13/)

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 580px) {
  .hide{
    display: none;
  }
}

    <a class="menu_button hide" href="#footer_nav" onclick="toggleNav(); return false;">&#9776;  MENU</a>
```

You can add a class to your menu button that tells it to hide when the display is bigger than 580px.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `onload` or `onDomReady`, your code is wrapped inside another function that is invoked on `load` or `ready` event. So, your function is not accessible from outside of that function so your javascript code will not work in jsFiddle.

Try this

```
.menu_button
{
     display:none;
}
```

[Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/a16qwd20/8/)

Answer (score -1):

Check https://jsfiddle.net/a16qwd20/7/

Basically, the js code needs to load post the element is loaded.

```
var originalNavClasses;

function toggleNav() {
    var elem = document.getElementById('navigation_list');
    var classes = elem.className;
    if (originalNavClasses === undefined) {
        originalNavClasses = classes;
    }
    elem.className = /expanded/.test(classes) ? originalNavClasses : originalNavClasses + ' expanded';
}
```